# How to define a command that temporarily modifies an option?

Tags: vimscript

I have the following two commands for making sure that `*` and `g*` move between small words containing `$` in a sensible way in `php`. I know it's possible to just modify the `iskeyword` option for the buffer as a whole, but I'm looking to avoid doing that.

I'm using the following `nnoremap` commands to make `*` and `g*` temporarily use a different value for `iskeyword`.

```
autocmd Filetype php nnoremap <silent> * :setlocal iskeyword+=\$<cr>*:setlocal iskeyword-=\$<cr>
autocmd Filetype php nnoremap <silent> g* :setlocal iskeyword+=\$<cr>g*:setlocal iskeyword-=\$<cr>
```

It works but it's a bit ugly and not very modular. Is there a way to factor out these definitions into separate commands or functions that cleanly override `iskeyword` and restore the old definition and handle potential errors correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a filetype plugin, for example `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`, you could try this code:

```
nno <buffer> <nowait> <silent> *  :<c-u>exe <sid>wrap_star(1)<cr>
nno <buffer> <nowait> <silent> g* :<c-u>exe <sid>wrap_star(0)<cr>

fu! s:wrap_star(whole) abort
    let isk_save = &l:isk
    setl isk+=$
    try
        exe 'norm! '.v:count1.(a:whole ? '' : 'g').'*'
    catch
        return 'echoerr '.string(v:exception)
    finally
        let &l:isk = isk_save
    endtry
    return ''
endfu
```

As your original code did, the `s:wrap_star()` function should temporarily add the `$` character to the buffer-local value of the `'iskeyword'` option. The command responsible for moving the cursor is:

```
exe 'norm! '.v:count1.(a:whole ? '' : 'g').'*'
```

It's wrapped inside a `try` conditional to handle a possible error. No matter what happens, that is even if an error occurs, the `finally` clause should remove the `$` character from `'iskeyword'`, before Vim finishes to process the function.

You can check this by adding a non-existing command, such as `:abcd`, inside the `try` conditional:

```
nno <buffer> <nowait> <silent> *  :<c-u>exe <sid>wrap_star(1)<cr>
nno <buffer> <nowait> <silent> g* :<c-u>exe <sid>wrap_star(0)<cr>

fu! s:wrap_star(whole) abort
    let isk_save = &l:isk
    setl isk+=$
    try
        abcd
        exe 'norm! '.v:count1.(a:whole ? '' : 'g').'*'
    catch
        return 'echoerr '.string(v:exception)
    finally
        let &l:isk = isk_save
    endtry
    return ''
endfu
```

If you hit `*` on a word, it should raise the error `E492`:

```
Vim:E492: Not an editor command:        abcd
```

After that, if you look at the value of `'isk'` (`:echo &l:isk`), you shouldn't find the `$` character.

---

Edit:

The `<c-u>` keycode removes all the characters between the cursor position and the beginning of the command-line. You are probably familiar with it, because it's a readline key binding which also works in a bash or zsh shell. When you have typed a wrong command, and you want to rewrite a new one, you can press `C-u` to kill the text from the cursor position up to the beginning.

It's not an obligation to use it, but it's a good habit. Watch this:

```
nno cd :echo 'hello'<cr>
```

Hit `cd`: it displays `hello`. Now, hit `2cd`: it raises the error:

```
E481: No range allowed
```

This is because, the `2` key that you pressed, combined with the first colon in the right-hand-side of your mapping, caused the following automatic translation:

```
2:    →    :.,.+1
```

So, `:echo` received the range `.,.+1` which means *from the current line, down to the next one*. But `:echo` doesn't accept a range, so it's an error.

In your case, it's the same thing, `:exe` doesn't accept a range. So, if you hit a number, you don't want `:exe` to be, wrongly, prefixed by a range.

If you press a number to repeat the motion, the function will still have access to it through the built-in variable `v:count1`.

See `:h c^u` for more info.

Comment: what does the `<c-u>` before `execute` in the commands do?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I edited the answer. If something is wrong or unclear, let me know, and I'll try to fix it.